# Rails basic auth not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am building a small API that uses basic authentication. What I have done, is that a user can generate a username and password, that could be used to authenticate to the API.

However I have discovered that it is not working 100% as intended. It appears that a request will slip through even though the username is not matching the password. However it will be blocked if the password is incorrect.

**Example**:
Username: `foo`
Password: `bar`

**Works**:
`curl -u foo:bar http://api/protected`

**Works - But should not**:
`curl -u f:bar http://api/protected`

**Does not work - As intended**:
`curl -u foo:b http://api/protected`

To me it appears that it only validates the password, and ignores the username. Here are some code.

```
# Authentication

protected

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    @user = User.includes(:keys).find_by( :keys => { :api_key => password } )
    @user.keys.each do |key|
      username == key.api_id && password == key.api_key  
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@user.keys.each do |key|
  username == key.api_id && password == key.api_key  
end
```

This piece of code returns a value of `.each`, which is the collection it's called on (`@user.keys` in this case). As it is a truthy value, the check will pass always, regardless of what are the results of evaluating your conditional in the block.

What you intended to ask is "Do any of user's keys match these credentials?". Use the appropriate method, `Enumerable#any?`

```
@user.keys.any? do |key|
  username == key.api_id && password == key.api_key  
end
```

Documentation: [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

Comment: This works perfect, thanks a bunch. However if the password or username is not found. It now throws and error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'keys' for nil:NilClass):
` Do you know why?

Comment: @madsobel: it's because `@user` is nil and you don't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@user = User.includes(:keys).find_by( :keys => { :api_key => password, :api_id => username } )
```

This way you'll make sure to find a user with valid both `username` and `password`, and you won't need the second line (iterating over keys).

The reason for that is: iterating over a block returns this block, not the value/values inside. So your authenticator found a user with a good password, iterated over his keys (which changed nothing) and returned `@user.keys`, which evaluates to `true`. Thus the authentication passed.

Comment: Interesting. Since when can activerecord do this (query by relation's attributes without explicit `joins`)? Could you insert a link to documentation, please?

Comment: OP included keys in his question, I thought the answer was explicit enough. I'll update it